# jQuery AutoSuggest Plugin - preFill options not working

Tags: jquery, forms, jquery-plugins

I'm using this [jQuery AutoSuggest Plugin.](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin)

It's pretty well documented, but there is a built-in option called preFill that doesn't seem to be working. A few people including myself have had this issue on their [support forum.](https://drew.tenderapp.com/discussions/autosuggest/24-an-issue-with-prefill)

We may just not be entering the option in correctly. There's not a good example in the documentation for how to enter in the option for preFill. Can anyone make sense of how this option should be formatted when it is defined?

Comment: Could you post the code you're using / the errors you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. Answer is on the [plugin forum.](https://drew.tenderapp.com/discussions/autosuggest/24-an-issue-with-prefill)